# Unable to add a comment on my Django blog

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've been trying to add comments to the forum on my website and I've managed to get to the stage of being able to see the comment form. But, when you actually submit the comment form, I get the below error.

FYI, 'What Good Marketing Events are There in 2020?' is the name of the post I'm trying to add a comment too.

[image]

Here are the models used:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField()
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name

class Post(models.Model):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is the view used:

```
def comment_post_form(request, pk):
    """ Create a view that allows us to add a comment """

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('forum_post_details.html', {'post': post})
    else:
        form = CommentPostForm()
        return render(request, 'comment_post_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the form used:

```
class CommentPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content']
```

Here is the 'for' statement used in the template:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
            <p>{{ comment.created_date }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.user_name }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
            {% empty %}
            <p>No comments added. Why not be the first!</p>
            {% endfor %}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need anything else, please let me know :)

Comment: Did you create the migration and applied it?

Comment: Ahh, rookie mistake... Forgot that I had updated the model name and therefore had to apply migrations again lol. Although, I have just got another error message which I don't know if you can help with? I've just added it at the bottom of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are redirecting is not how you do it. You can use the redirect() function in a number of ways.

url.py

```
path('teacherprofile/', views.teacher_profile_view, name='teacher-profile'),
```

views.py

By passing the name of a view

```
return redirect('teacher-profile')
```

By passing a hardcoded URL to redirect to:

```
return redirect(teacherprofile/)
```

This also works with full URLs:

```
 return redirect('https://example.com/')
```

This way the user is redirect the html page itself.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm confused on what needs to be amended in my view? I've changed it to be `return redirect('forum_post_details')`, but that won't work as it needs to know the post id.

Comment: I can see what you mean now :) Managed to get it working. Thanks for your help! @ngawang13